# Anyone have experience with PythonTeX?

Tags: xetex, python, pygments, pythontex

I have been trying to get PythonTeX working, but can't seem to solve the errors I'm getting.

My current Minimum Broken Example is this:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\usepackage[pyfuture=all]{pythontex}

\begin{document}
Hello world!

\begin{pycode}
print "foo"
\end{pycode}

\end{document}
```

Which, unless I'm misunderstanding the documentation, should output `foo` into that location in the LaTeX document.

Almost all the other features are working, such as the console emulation mode:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\usepackage[pyfuture=all]{pythontex}

\begin{document}
Hello world!

\begin{pyconsole}
x = 123
y = 345
z = x + y
z
def f(expr):
    return(expr**4)

f(x)
print('Python says hi from the console!')
\end{pyconsole}

\end{document}
```

So does anyone have any idea why the pycode environment doesn't work?

---

Edit: More information:

It seems I confused things, above.

I've found (though it took longer than I'd like to admit) that this does work:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\usepackage[]{pythontex}

\begin{document}
\begin{pycode}
print("hello")
\end{pycode}
\end{document}
```

But regardless of having `pyfuture=all` selected or not, why cant I use the `python 2.7` `print "foo"` syntax? I get the following error:

```
This is PythonTeX 0.14

----  Messages for py:default:default  ----
* PythonTeX stderr - error on line 19:
    File "<outputdir>/py_default_default.py", line 54
      print "hello"
                  ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And one last question, can I pre-import things into the console emulator? Something like this, but this doesn't work:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\usepackage[]{pythontex}


\begin{document}
foo

\begin{pycode}
import math
\end{pycode}
\begin{pyconsole}
math.sqrt(25)
\end{pyconsole}

\end{document}
```

Should I just try to switch everything to `python 3`?

Comment: If you have `pyfuture=all`, I think you want `print("foo")`, with the parentheses for the `print()` function. Have you tried that? Also, giving the actual error messages would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks so much for replying, I've updated my answer with what I figured out since asking.

Comment: It looks like you want `pyfuture=none` (no auto imports from `__future__`) and the `pyconcode` environment. I can add a more detailed answer later.

Comment: is `pyfuture=none` not the default? I assumed it was... Is there a way to be explicit about what to pull in from `__future__`? If I know I want `division`, for example? Thanks for taking the time, and thanks for the awesome package!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the issues are related to Python's `__future__` module, which allows Python 3 features to be imported in Python 2. Imports from `__future__` can be performed manually. However, by default PythonTeX brings in three things:

- `print_function`
- `absolute_import`
- `division`

This corresponds to the package option `pyfuture=default`. Basically, the default behavior is to behave as much like Python 3 as possible without a significant chance of conflicts. The only other possible import from `__future__` for Python 2.7 is `unicode_literals`, but when I was creating the package a few years ago, that could cause problems with some packages. Things should be better now, but I expect that an occasional conflict is still possible.

If you want to add `unicode_literals`, you can use `pyfuture=all`. If you want no automatic imports from `__future__`, just use the package option `pyfuture=none`, and then import from `__future__` as you normally would.

Regarding your console question, the `pyconcode` environment will execute within the console session, but show no output.  Everything console-related starts with the prefix `pycon`. Also note that the console treatment of automatic `__future__` imports is governed by the package option `pyconfuture`.

Comment: Makes sense why the console was different from the `pycode` environment now, thanks! Thanks for explaining and thanks for writing the package.